# How to use jQuery.end()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

From what I read in the docs, end() will return the initial object. In my case this should return `$(this)`, right?

```
$('.el').delegate('a.off', 'click', function(){
  $(this).parents('div').find('a').removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
  ...
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I don't get the `addClass('active')` applied on the original element (the link `a.off`).

Comment: Personally, I prefer more readable code rather than these long jQuery chains with tricky stack manipulation that are hard to understand/read.  Just add: `$(this).addClass('active');` as the second line of your click handler and skip the use of `.end()`.  Code should first be correct, then readable, and only then as brief as it can without compromising the previous two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the initial object, the *previously* selected elements, which would be `.parents('div')` in this case. Think about it as a stack and every time you change the selection of elements, they get added to the stack, and `.end()` removes the last entry of the stack. You'd have to call `.end()` twice.

But instead you can also rearrange your method calls and use `not` to filter out the particular element:

```
$(this)
  .addClass('active')
  .parents('div')
  .find('a').not(this)
  .removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct but I'm not sure what's happening with your code,  I made this example and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/UKwzw/

Never mind.  I missed the "removeClass" part.